# Illustrator changing my CMYK values even in a CMYK document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk, swatches

My illustrator is changing my cmyk colors and even swatches to random numbers, I was changing CMYK red to 98% yellow 97% magenta, and now worse, it changes cmyk black to 70%c, 67%m, 64%y, 74%k. Mind you, the swatch name is even "c=0 m=0 y=0 k=100", it's the very base swatch that comes with the default swatch pallete. If I try to edit the swatch and change it to the correct values, when I apply it again it still applies this mess of numbers.

My document is cmyk as you can see in the print. I can't figure out what the hell is up.

[image: here is a print]

Comment: Might help if you actually showed the swatch (not color picker). Your not pasting the rgb values in are you? Anyway there's no information in your question that lets us of anything other than guess

Comment: Just noticed this happening as well. RGB doc colour setting. Specified 10/20/15/40, saved swatch. Specified Swatch colour to type. Select all in that colour and it's saying some whack mix. This never used to happen.Changed doc colour setup to CMYK to test, went back in to the type, and it's yet another mix. Ridiculous.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot that actually shows that the document is in CMYK mode? This behavior is consistent with a document in RGB mode.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is an issue to do with colour management settings. Different colour profiles show different colour values. Revisit and take a closer look at your colour profile settings.

Comment: No they dont. The numbers you use are the numbers you use profile tells what those numbers mean.

Comment: I hear you @joojaa, but try this:

Draw a rectangle in a ISO Coated V2 (ECI) document and fill it with a red colour (C=0 M=100 Y=100 K=0)
Copy it to a U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) V2 document 

Notice how the values have been altered.

Comment: Yes obviously if you change your working space it changes also if you copypaste rgb values.... But not within the same document. Your space is your space. Thats what the numbers tell you. But its a bit pointless to try to figure out what OP is doing there is just no info